# Как отпимально извлекать и обрабатывать большое количество строк из базы данных в Java-коде?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица на миллионы строк вида `id(int) + name(varchar)`. То есть, всего два столбца.

Нужно создать метод, который будет выбирать из таблицы все значения `name`, которые соответствуют какому-то паттерну. Паттерн подается на вход метода как regexp. Главное условие: проверка на соответствие паттерну должна производиться в java коде. На уровне базы проверки запрещены.

Получается, нужно каким-то образом выбирать из базы миллионы строк, помещать их в память и там уже проверять. Большинство решений "в лоб" выглядят очень медленными. Какие самые оптимальные способы решения такой проблемы?

P.S вопрос чисто теоретический, к реальным приложениям отношения не имеет

Comment: Рассмотри данный вариант https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/

Comment: @Antonio112009 вся соль как раз, чтобы не делать проверок на уровне базы, только в приложении

Comment: ссори, не так прочел. Вы случайно Hibernate ORM не используете? Или по хардкору - чистый SQL

Comment: @Antonio112009 тут не важен используется какой-либо фрейморк или нет, важно получить максимальную производительность и стабильность для такой операции на очень больших массивах данных. Так что, если есть хорошее решение на Hibernate - я бы с удовольствием послушал.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на GutHub)

Answer (score 2):

На ум приходит алгоритм: 1 выбрать из бд количество строк в таблице. 2 создать новые потоки для обработки патерна (количество потоков соответствует числу ядер процесора). 3 разделить число строк на количество потоков. 4 выбрать из базы в постраничном режиме данные. 5 обработать коллекцию объектов. Думаю что быстрее может быть при таком подходе только с наращиванием железа.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка на проект в [Github](https://github.com/Antonio112009/SO_Answer)

Написал мини-программу с помощью Hibernate ORM. В лоб протестил 100`000 строк данных.

Почему 2 раза делаю одно и тоже действие?
Hibernate "просыпается" в первом случае, а во втором уже стабильно работает.

Отправка данных в БД - **2мин 3сек**
Взять все данные из БД - **1сек 578мс**

Попробую улучшить скорость. Ссылку на файл сделаю чуть позже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Update 1:

После нескольких тестов - 111'000 данных я смог стабильно получить за **900мс**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]